# Metamask: Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted]

Tags: solidity, metamask, error

I am trying to work with the smart contract I found on: https://github.com/pappas999/Parametric-Crop-Insurance/blob/main/contracts/Crop-Insurance.sol

I can deploy the contract but when I try to interact with the function newContract I always receive the metamask error "Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted]". Perhaps someone now how to solve it? It would be really great. I don`t really know what to do and where it come from..

I am using the code:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;


//Imports 

import "https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.4/Aggregator.sol";
import "https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.4/vendor/Ownable.sol";
import "https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.4/interfaces/LinkTokenInterface.sol";
import "https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.4/interfaces/AggregatorInterface.sol";
import "https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.4/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol";
import "https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.4/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


contract InsuranceProvider {

    using SafeMathChainlink for uint; //using SafeMath for uint means that the functions contained in the SafeMath.sol library can be used directly on objects of type uint
    address public insurer = msg.sender; //msg.sender will be the person who's currently connecting with the contract
    AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed; 

    uint public constant DAY_IN_SECONDS = 60; //How many seconds in a day. 60 for testing, 86400 for Production

    uint256 constant private ORACLE_PAYMENT = 0.1 * 10**18; // 0.1 LINK
    address public constant LINK_KOVAN = 0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088 ; //address of LINK token on Kovan https://docs.chain.link/docs/link-token-contracts/

 
    //here is where all the insurance contracts are stored.
    mapping (address => InsuranceContract) contracts;


    constructor()   public payable {
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331); //The constructor() {} initializes an interface object named priceFeed that uses AggregatorV3Interface and connects specifically to a proxy aggregator contract that is already deployed at 0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331
    }

    /**
     * @dev Prevents a function being run unless it's called by the Insurance Provider https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol#L28
    */

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(insurer == msg.sender, 'Only Insurance provider can do this');
        _;
    }
     

   /**
    * @dev Event to log when a contract is created
    */
    event contractCreated(address _insuranceContract, uint _premium, uint _totalCover);


    /**
     * @dev Create a new contract for client, automatically approved and deployed to the blockchain
     */
    function newContract(address _client, uint _duration, uint _premium, uint _payoutValue, string _cropLocation) public payable onlyOwner() returns(address) {
       
        //return(addresses){}in den Klappemern spezifiziert man welche adresse genau herausgegeben werden muss
        //create contract, send payout amount so contract is fully funded plus a small buffer
        InsuranceContract i = (new InsuranceContract).value((_payoutValue * 1 ether).div(uint(getLatestPrice())))(_client, _duration, _premium, _payoutValue, _cropLocation, LINK_KOVAN, ORACLE_PAYMENT);
        contracts[address(i)] = i;  //store insurance contract in contracts Map

        //emit an event to say the contract has been created and funded
        emit contractCreated(address(i), msg.value, _payoutValue);

        //now that contract has been created, we need to fund it with enough LINK tokens to fulfil 1 Oracle request per day, with a small buffer added
        LinkTokenInterface link = LinkTokenInterface(i.getChainlinkToken());
        link.transfer(address(i), ((_duration.div(DAY_IN_SECONDS)) + 2) * ORACLE_PAYMENT.mul(2));


        return address(i);

    }


    /**
     * @dev returns the contract for a given address
     */
    function getContract(address _contract) external view returns (InsuranceContract) {
        return contracts[_contract];
    }

    /**
     * @dev updates the contract for a given address
     */
    function updateContract(address _contract) external {
        InsuranceContract i = InsuranceContract(_contract);
        i.updateContract();
    }

    /**
     * @dev gets the current rainfall for a given contract address
     */
    function getContractRainfall(address _contract) external view returns(uint) {
        InsuranceContract i = InsuranceContract(_contract);
        return i.getCurrentRainfall();
    }

    /**
     * @dev gets the current rainfall for a given contract address
     */
    function getContractRequestCount(address _contract) external view returns(uint) {
        InsuranceContract i = InsuranceContract(_contract);
        return i.getRequestCount();
    }



    /**
     * @dev Get the insurer address for this insurance provider
     */
    function getInsurer() external view returns (address) {
        return insurer;
    }



    /**
     * @dev Get the status of a given Contract
     */
    function getContractStatus(address _address) external view returns (bool) {
        InsuranceContract i = InsuranceContract(_address);
        return i.getContractStatus();
    }

    /**
     * @dev Return how much ether is in this master contract
     */
    function getContractBalance() external view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Function to end provider contract, in case of bugs or needing to update logic etc, funds are returned to insurance provider, including any remaining LINK tokens
     */
    function endContractProvider() external payable onlyOwner() {
        LinkTokenInterface link = LinkTokenInterface(LINK_KOVAN);
        require(link.transfer(msg.sender, link.balanceOf(address(this))), "Unable to transfer");
        selfdestruct(insurer);
    }



    /**
     * Returns the latest price
     */
    function getLatestPrice() public view returns (int) {
        (   uint80 roundID,
            int price,
            uint startedAt,
            uint timeStamp,
            uint80 answeredInRound
        ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        // If the round is not complete yet, timestamp is 0
        require(timeStamp > 0, "Round not complete");
        return price;
    }

    /**
     * @dev fallback function, to receive ether
     */
    function() external payable {  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot post a comment so I will delete this answer soon.

Please post a more adequate code sample, ideally just the function you are interacting with alongside everything that function uses.

Comment: Thank you for the hint:) I changed it a little bit. I hope it is better now:)